# Upgrading Django 1.1.1 to 1.3.1, admin.autodiscover() raises exception asking for contenttypes

Tags: django, exception, admin, contenttypes

I switched a 1.1.1 Django project to 1.3.1. Upon calling admin.autodiscover() in urls.py, an exception is raised from sites.py in the admin framework stating:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Put 'django.contrib.contenttypes' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order 
to use the admin application
```

In settings.py, I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'my.app'
)
```

Things I checked:

1. The contenttypes framework is indeed in my INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. I have not repeated my INSTALLED_APPS declaration anywhere else
3. The contenttypes entry in INSTALLED_APPS is listed before the admin entry.
4. Running django-admin.py shell and importing "django.contrib.contenttypes" works.

If I go to the offending lines in the admin (Django-1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in check_dependencies, line 164), I see:

```
if not ContentType._meta.installed:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(...)
```

If I comment out the check, I can run my project and the admin works. I'm not sure how the _meta.installed property is supposed to be set on model types, so I am at a loss for what to do next.

I should also note that this same Django 1.3.1 installation is working with other projects using similar settings files.

Any hints or resources would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just an aside, (but related) django 1.4 is in beta right now. Django 1.4RC is due out February 27, and 1.4final is due out March 05 (per the release schedule). Waiting a couple weeks could save you from two upgrade migrations, rather than one big one.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4-beta-1/#the-django-1-4-roadmap

Comment: Would be good if you post your INSTALLED_APPS here

Comment: Have you verified that the package exists in your new installation location? Something like <python_root>/site_packages/django/contrib/contenttypes.

Comment: Posted INSTALLED_APPS as requested. The contenttypes package exists, and there are other projects that are successfully using this 1.3.1 install w/ similar settings files.

Comment: model._meta.installed is being set [pretty straightforward](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/options.py#L71) and this has not been changed since 1.1.1 so it should be working fine. Try to check (via print or pdb) what is the real value of settings.INSTALLED_APPS and ContentType._meta.installed

Answer (score 1):

django.contrib.contenttypes includes two models, ContentType and ContentTypeManager. My guess is that you haven't run `manage.py syncdb` after adding django.contrib.contenttypes to your INSTALLED_APPS.

This would make the `if not ContentType._meta.installed` check understandable: the ContentType model isn't available in the database yet.